# How to do this join query in Laravel way?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

```sql
select tb_addquestion.UserId, COUNT(*) AS count from `tb_addquestion` 
 left join `tb_user` on `tb_user`.`UserId` = `tb_addquestion`.`UserId`
 GROUP BY(tb_addquestion.UserId) having count > 0 AND count < 15
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for "other people doing my work" please describe what you already tried and where are the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
DB::table('tb_addquestion')
    ->leftJoin('tb_user', 'tb_user.UserId', 'tb_addquestion.UserId')
    ->groupBy('tb_addquestion.UserId')
    ->having('count', '>', 0)
    ->having('count', '<', 15)
    ->select('tb_addquestion.UserId', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS count'));
```

Comment: good answer, but a question without code should never be answered.

Comment: No, thats not needed (in my opinion), just a tip for the future